# Kinect fusion with Kinect 2.0

Tags: kinect

I am looking for a code which will able to perform kinect fusion as done by [Newcombe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ismar2011.pdf) with Kinect v2.0 . I know that that principle used for Kinect 1 is different from the principle used for Kinect 2.0 . I have found one famous open source library which does this, pcl. But The code is specific for kinect 1.0. Is there any opensource library which can do this for Kinect 2.0. If not is there a way I can refactor the current open source codes to make it for 2.0 . If I am refactoring the code for 2.0 then is there anything else I have to modify other than, changing the resolution of the camera outputs? Is there a way I can compensate for extra noisy result given by Kinect 2.0 other than increasing the smoothing in bilateral filtering. Is there a way I can handle the extra distorted results given by Kinect 2.0? I looking to use libfreenect2.

Thanks :)

Comment: THe Kinect SDK 2.0 has all the codes for Kinect Fusion in C# and C++ ... You can use that as a start point. Just download and install the sdk.

Comment: Kinect SDKs by Microsoft which support kinect fusion for 2.0 are available only in windows OS. I want to use Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: For Ubuntu, I believe that Kintinuous is the next best adaptation of Kinect Fusion that is opensource. Plus it also caters for the reconstruction volume limitations. (https://github.com/mp3guy/Kintinuous)

Comment: It is great tool to use, but i was looking at a system where the volumetric representation as same as the one mentioned in the original kinect fusion paper as i was looking at extending the method for other applications. And I dont really need to worry about big scenes.